# how to get mobile number in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am using "mobile_number(version - 1.0.3)" plugin to get mobile number in flutter app, am running in original device but i couldn't get mobile number.instead of errors i can get mobile number as null along with other sim details as shown in screen shot.

help me to resolve this problem, i had just copy pasted the example given by plugin that is the code
[image]
[plugin link](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number)

Comment: I think there is some issues in this package because  it's not working in oppo mobile phone.

Comment: Not working on Android 11 and Android 12

Answer (score 0):

It says:
*Note: If the mobile number is not pre-exist on sim card it will not return te phone number.*

I think mobile number does not pre-exist on the SIM if the SIM is not original (i.e. replaced)

Comment: can i get without plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

If the phone number isn't stored on the sim (aka null), then you can't get it from anywhere else, in that case you probably want to forward the user to a different page where they can type the phone number using TextField and then store it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mobile_number](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_number) package to get mobile number and other details. For example

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mobile_number/mobile_number.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _mobileNumber = '';
  List<SimCard> _simCard = <SimCard>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MobileNumber.listenPhonePermission((isPermissionGranted) {
      if (isPermissionGranted) {
        initMobileNumberState();
      } else {}
    });

    initMobileNumberState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initMobileNumberState() async {
    if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
      await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
      return;
    }
    String mobileNumber = '';
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      mobileNumber = (await MobileNumber.mobileNumber)!;
      _simCard = (await MobileNumber.getSimCards)!;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Failed to get mobile number because of '${e.message}'");
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    });
  }

  Widget fillCards() {
    List<Widget> widgets = _simCard
        .map((SimCard sim) => Text(
            'Sim Card Number: (${sim.countryPhonePrefix}) - ${sim.number}\nCarrier Name: ${sim.carrierName}\nCountry Iso: ${sim.countryIso}\nDisplay Name: ${sim.displayName}\nSim Slot Index: ${sim.slotIndex}\n\n'))
        .toList();
    return Column(children: widgets);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Running on: $_mobileNumber\n'),
              fillCards()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```